# A mail LinkedList code

Tags: java, linked-list

I am able to run below code. But I am not getting how tostring() method [BOLDED PART] is getting called in this. Need ur help in understanding this flow.

```
import java.util.*;

class Address{  

    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String code;

    Address(String n, String s, String c, String st, String cd) {
        name = n;
        street = s;
        city = c;
        state = st;
        code = cd;      
    }
```

---

```
**public String toString(){
        return name + " " + street + " " + city + " " + state + " " + code;
    }**

}
```

---

```
public class eighth {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        LinkedList<Address> ml = new LinkedList<Address>();
        ml.add(new Address("aman","sultanwind","asr","punjab","143001"));
        ml.add(new Address("ram","mg road","kochi","kerala","132555"));
        ml.add(new Address("shyam","atta","noida","up","201301"));

        System.out.println("contents of ml "+ml);


    }

}
```

Comment: Your `System.out.println()` is invoking that . SYSOUT is invoking the `toString()` of `LinkedList` which in turn the `String.valueOf(element)` which in turn the `toString()` of `Address` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the line that calls the ToString method.

```
System.out.println("contents of ml "+ml);
```

As The New Idiot says, using + on an object to concatenate a string to it calls ToString on it.  This means that ToString is called on the LinkedList.  This in turn calls ToString on Address.